# Flutter Laravel: Uploading an image using Dio and ImagePicker

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, dart, dio

I'm unable to upload an image to my Laravel server from Flutter using Dio and ImagePicker when a request in Postman returns a successful response

**Postman:**
[postman_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLNb8.png)

**Laravel:**

```php
public function uploadFile(Request $request) {
        if($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $name = time()."_".$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->file('image')->move(public_path('images'), $name);
        }
        return response()->json([
            asset("images/$name"),
            201,
            'message' => asset("images/$name") ? 'Image saved' : 'Image failed to save'
        ]);
    }
```

**Flutter:**

```dart
Future getImage(context) async {
    var image = await picker.getImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
        imageQuality: 50,
        maxHeight: 500.0,
        maxWidth: 500.0);
    imageFile = File(image.path);
    _uploadFile(imageFile);
  }

  _uploadFile(File file) async {
    String name = file.path.split('/').last;
    var data = FormData.fromMap({
      "name": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
        file.path,
        filename: name,
      ),
    });

    Dio dio = new Dio();
    await dio
        .post("http://localhost:8000/api/upload-file", data: data)
        .then((response) => print(response))
        .catchError((error) => print(error));
  }
```

The server side error: `Http status error [500] Undefined variable *name* in file ...`

Answer (score 1):

Would you try again after changing with below code?

```
 var data = FormData.fromMap({
      "image": await MultipartFile.fromFile(
        file.path,
        filename: name,
      ),
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @kuku, i figured that after. Was using name instead of image

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, it works for me:

```
List<MultipartFile> multiFiles = [];
for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
multiFiles.add(await MultipartFile.fromPath('profile_photo[]', files[i].path));
}
request.files.addAll(multiFiles);
```